# Sqlite3 data ending on 40

Tags: node.js

```
let db = new sqlite3.Database('./db/usermutehistory.db');
  // construct the insert statement with multiple placeholders
  // based on the number of rows
  let sql = 'SELECT Who who, Made made, Reason reason FROM UsersMuteHistory where Who = ? ';
  // output the INSERT statement
   let who = search.id
   db.each(sql, [who], (err, row) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    console.log(row);
    let logchannel = message.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "logs");
    var mutehistory = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setAuthor("Fury-Bot", bot.user.avatarURL)
  .setColor('#FF0000')
  .addField(`Who`, `<@${row.who}>`,true)
  .addField(`Made`, `<@${row.made}>`,true)
  .addField(`Reason`, row.reason);
  logchannel.send(mutehistory);

  });
```

Every time i call the row.who or the row.made it shows me allways the ending of 40 but on database it ends on other numbers.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsJwe.jpg = the output
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWalw.jpg = data on database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript does not have a built-in `Number` representation for a number that large. I would consider using a string.